# If a group (or module) admits a finite composition series,is it possible that it has normal series (submodule series) of arbitrary length?

Tags: group-theory, modules

> If a group (or module) admits a finite composition series,is it possible that it has normal series (submodule series) of arbitrary length?

I think it is impossible, but I can't find a proof in website, could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, do not put the question only in the title. It needs to appear in the body of the post as well. I've taken the liberty to do that for you. Also, you may omit thanks.  It would really be better if you said a bit about  what you know and don't know regarding your efforts.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for pointing out my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic words are "Schreier refinement Theorem".

Comment: @rschwieb If there exist a chain of arbitrary length,I think the thm could be used to refine both the composition series and the chain to an isomorphic refinement.But any refinement of a composition series is itself.So the chain could be refined to a composition series.Is my understanding right?I'm uncertain about it...

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry,I'm confused..I don't know where is the mistake in the last comment I made..Could you point it out ?Thanks...

Comment: @likemath Originally I thought the problem was applying it to an infinite chain, but of course you could use a finite series longer than your composition series instead .  Now I see the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

For modules, I would say the easiest idea would be to use the characterization of modules with finite composition series as those which are both Artinian and Noetherian. You can find a proof of this, for example, in Martin Isaacs' *Graduate algebra* Theorem 11.3 [[google books]](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&dq=editions%3AjWYrTFFhOdIC&q=146#v=snippet&q=146&f=false),
 or [here on page 3](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/JH.pdf).

I expect the same should be true for groups but I really can't find an analogous statement for groups which would work the same way (although it clearly holds for abelian groups, which are just $\mathbb Z$ modules.)

The only hint I had in the positive direction was this exercise in the second link above:
[image]

But I'm reluctant to declare that as the final word since I couldn't find it elsewhere and haven't verified it.

Comment: Thanks for you help.